# wget timeout -- keeps 'trying'

Tags: linux, wget, opensuse

I'm downloading about 100 files right now with the 'default' configuration on wget. I'm stuck on one package (I suspect the package has moved) and wget keeps retrying. I figured that after 3 or so tries it would move on to the next URL, but it isn't.

I'm on try number 7 and I've been waiting about 20 minutes. If I do have to restart the wget script, will it skip the packages I already have?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the max number of tries using `-t #` or `--tries=#`. You can also add `-nc` or `--no-clobber` to your wget commandline, which will prevent it from overwriting existing files.

http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Download-Options.html#Download-Options